# I got an uitoolbar bug when I change state of uiviews subviews.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitoolbar

Basic idea, I need to block user interaction when I'm receiving internet datas. And when I got all data I need to unblock user interaction. After unblocking user interaction my UIToolBar items didn't got any touches.

I created a simple code that demonstrate this behavior.

Firstly I created UISplitViewController. On DetailsViewController I added UIToolBar with one item.

**DetailViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  __block UIView *myView = self.view;
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [AppDelegate setInteraction:NO onView:myView];
    [AppDelegate setInteraction:YES onView:myView];
 });
}
```

**AppDelegate**

```
+ (void)setInteraction:(BOOL)allow onView:(UIView *)aView {
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [aView setUserInteractionEnabled:allow];
        for (UIView * v in [aView subviews]) {
            [self setInteraction:allow onView:v];
        }
 });
}
```

After unblocking user interaction my UIToolBar items didn't got any touches.

Answer (score 0):

in aView's subviews might probably your tool bar but not the bar button.
May be you can just add a clear background mask view to block the interaction and remove it to allow user interact again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that happened to me once when calling a modal view. Try storing the toolbar items before your internet code and restoring them afterwards like this:

```
NSArray *storeToolbarItems = self.toolbar.items;
self.toolbar.items = nil;

//Execute your code to disable/enable interaction and receive internet data
//Once you have re-enabled user interaction... 
[self.toolbar setItems:storeToolbarItems];
```